# Databinding Angular 2 reactive forms to json data

Tags: rest, angular, formbuilder

I am using angular 2 data driven (reactive) forms. I am, trying to find a better way to map json data from a rest call to my form builder form. Currently, I am doing something like the following :

```
this.courseForm = this.fb.group({
    "Title": this.Title,
    "Author": this.Author
});

this.courseService.getCourse(id).then((course) => {
    this.courseForm.controls.Title.setValue(course.Title);
    this.courseForm.controls.Author.setValue(course.Author);
})

<input type="text" formControlName="Title" />
<input type="text" formControlName="Author" />
```

It works, but requires I individually map each control to each property from the json object. With template driven forms, I only needed to do the following:

```
course: any[];

this.courseService.getCourse(id).then((course) => {
    this.course = course;
})

<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="course.Title" />
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="course.Author" />
```

Not sure if I am missing something simple when it comes to binding data driven forms to json objects.

Comment: You can use `patchValue` and pass in an entire object and it will try its best to map it to your form model.  If the object is the same schema as the form, you can use `setValue`.

Answer (score 0):

dustmouse provide the answer in a comment. My json and form schema are identical, so all I had to do was the following to map the entire json object to the form:

```
this.courseForm.setValue(course, {selfOnly: true });
```

Piece of cake. Thanks dustmouse!